# How do i pass filters to django tastypie

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

Am a bit puzzled by this behavior of django tastypie, am attempting to pass a filter to my resource via backbone.js but nothing get returned.

My Resource class looks like this;

```
class TenderResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Tender.objects.all()
            authorization = Authorization()
            list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
            detail_allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'tender'
        filtering = {
                'dept_ref':ALL,
                }
```

My URLconf file looks like this;

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(TenderResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', DocView.as_view(), name='docview'),
    url(r'^api/$', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

Within my apps.js, containing backbone logic, my url that calls the resource with filter looks like this;

```
TENDER_API = "/api/v1/tender/?dept_ref=119/";
```

But when i run the application no result are returned!, if i take this URL and run it straight from the browser i.e.

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tender/?dept_ref=119/"
```

i receive the json result from the resource;

**BUT ...**

When i pass the following URL with NO filter from my application i receive all the data;

```
TENDER_API = "/api/v1/tender/";
```

What am i missing? or What is the best way to pass filters to django tastypie?

Gath

Comment: Could the trailing slash be a problem? That is how about `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tender/?dept_ref=119"` instead of `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/tender/?dept_ref=119/"` ?

Comment: nope, tried both but nothing works

Comment: So I think this is more of a backbone.js issue than django/tastypie. From my experience, there is just not much that can go wrong here. Is it possible for you to check what exactly is the request made by backbone (e.g. using Firebug) ?

Comment: Btw, the indentation in the first snippet you pasted is wrong. There is also the Authorization() class which might play a role here.

Comment: But am curious why it works fine straight from the browser... thought Authentication would block that request to..

Comment: [This][1] question answered mine!

Thanks.

Gath


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063291/backbone-js-collection-and-tastypie-filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of searches i got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063291/backbone-js-collection-and-tastypie-filters) question in SO that answered mine perfectly well.

Basically you add filtering to your tastypie resource file,

```
class TenderResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        ....
        filtering = {
                       "dept_ref":ALL
                    }
```

then you pass the filter as javascript object called "data" via your backbone collections.fetch method with

```
MyCollection.fetch({data:{"dept_ref":"119"}})
```